# Creating Bootstrap table with differents Angular components

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap table using two Angular components.

My code is organised as following :

```
componentA.html
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">First</th>
  <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
  <componentB></componentB>
 </tbody>
</table>



componentB.html
<tr>
 <th scope="row">1</th>
 <td>Mark</td>
 <td>Otto</td>
 <td>mdo</td>
</tr>
```

The result should be like this :
[image: expected]

but it's actually like this :
[image: reality]

However, it works fine when I put the HTML content of componentB directly in componentA html.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the scope on tr tag : `<th scope="row">1</th>`

Then table element in HTML just allows thead, tbody, tfoot and tr as children.

Change your componentB selector from 'componentB' to '[componentB]'

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">First</th>
  <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody componentB>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are right, I did a poor copy past and forgot that line, but my code was tested with <th scope="row">1</th> and it didn't worked

Comment: trying to fix it, the problem should be from the <componentb> not allowed as a tag into a table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's inadvised by Angular best practices to do so. (sources : https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03)

Comment: Such case is covered by the exception paragraph  : as you can't include non html table children tags, you can only "augment built-in elements."

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">First</th>
    <th scope="col">Last</th>
    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yeah this is working, but I need to use two differents components in order to create dynamics tables